# How do you read and store a UTF-8 value in Michelson

Tags: tezos-client, michelson, string

The [Michelson document](https://tezos.gitlab.io/008/michelson.html#constants) from the Tezos Developers Resources page states the following about the `string` type:

> Strings, with some usual escape sequences: \n, \, ". Unescaped
> line-breaks (both \n and \r) cannot appear in a Michelson string.
> Moreover, the current version of Michelson restricts strings to be the
> printable subset of 7-bit ASCII, namely characters with codes from
> within [32, 126] range, plus the escaped characters mentioned above.

It sounds like that is not a good type to hold a UTF-8 value. It looks like there is another type `bytes`. The [documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/008/michelson.html#operations-on-bytes) says the following.

> Bytes are used for serializing data, in order to check signatures and
> compute hashes on them. They can also be used to incorporate data from
> the wild and untyped outside world.

This might be a good type to store UTF-8 value, but how do I use it?

For example, let's say I want to store a Russian phrase `Привет, мир` in a Michelson contract that has an entrypoint `store_message` with a parameter `bytes` that updates the storage to that value. If I am using the tezos-client, what operations do I need to perform on that string before sending it to the entrypoint. Then when the storage is updated and I read the storage from the contract, what operation do I need to perform on `bytes` to convert it back into the original message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byte sequences in Michelson are written in hexadecimal with a leading `0x`. To convert between this representation and reguar UTF8 strings, you can use any tool that is dumb enough to iterate over UTF8 strings byte-per-byte; here is a solution using bash and `tezos-codec`:

```
# Encoding an UTF8 string as Michelson bytes
$ MSG='"Привет, мир"'
$ ENCODED_STRING=$(tezos-codec encode ground.string from "$MSG")
$ ENCODED_BYTES=$(tezos-codec decode ground.bytes from "$ENCODED_STRING")
$ MICHELSON_BYTES="0x$(echo $ENCODED_BYTES | cut -d \" -f 2)"
$ echo $MICHELSON_BYTES
0xd09fd180d0b8d0b2d0b5d1822c20d0bcd0b8d180
```

```
# Decoding Michelson bytes as an UTF8 string
$ MICHELSON_BYTES=0xd09fd180d0b8d0b2d0b5d1822c20d0bcd0b8d180
$ ENCODED_BYTES="\"$(echo $MICHELSON_BYTES | cut -d x -f 2)\""
$ ENCODED_STRING=$(tezos-codec encode ground.bytes from "$ENCODED_BYTES")
$ MSG=$(tezos-codec decode ground.string from "$ENCODED_STRING")
$ echo $MSG
"Привет, мир"
```

This relies on the fact that the ground binary encodings for strings and byte sequences are identical but the JSON encodings are different.